# Is there a way in Google Sheets to track connected sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I maintain the internal data for a small company.  We utilize Google Sheets exclusively.  I use the 'importrange' function quite often, and am wondering, is there a way to track A) How many connections there are to a specific sheet and/or B)list which sheets are connected?

I am revising some of my 'core' sheets, and want to ensure I migrate ALL other connected sheets to the new data source.

For example, I have a company roster let's call it SheetX.  If I redesign SheetX and call the new spreadsheet SheetY, how can make sure all other sheets are now importing data from SheetY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the AppsScript function you can use to enumerate all URLs referenced by any `IMPORTRANGE` formula in the active spreadsheet:

```
function enumerateDependencies(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sheets = ss.getSheets()
  const referencedUrls = []
  for(const sh of sheets){
    const formulas = sh.getDataRange().getFormulas().flat().map(formula=>formula.toUpperCase())
    
    const importRangeFormulas = formulas.filter(formula=>formula.match(/^=.*IMPORTRANGE\(/) )
    for(const formula of importRangeFormulas){
      const m = formula.match(/"(HTTPS?:\/\/.*?)"/)
      if(m && m[1]){
        if(referencedUrls.indexOf(m[1])<0){
          referencedUrls.push(m[1])
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(referencedUrls)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the timely response.  Do you know if there would be a way to reverse the process?

Comment: you mean to find all spreadsheets from which the active file is referenced? I am afraid not, because it would involve too much time and theoretically infinite runtime